# How shift all glassfish ports?

Tags: java, glassfish

I want run several glassfish instances. So I have to use different port in all instances. At now I have found that glassfish uses several ports:

1. `8080` for http requests
2. `8181` for https requests
3. `4848` for admin colsole
4. `9009` for debug
5. `8686` for jmx

First of all is it full list or not? Or where I can find full list?

The second is there a setting to shift all ports? Supose I set `shift_pots=5` and every port number increased by 5. So it can be convinient for configure everal instances. Is it possible or I have to manually set every port?

Answer (score 0):

I did not know any way when your domain is already setup to shift all ports without doing it manually for all ports with the asadmin commands or editing the domain.xml. A list of the default ports you maybe need to change can be found at [Table 1-1 Default Administration Values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/overview.htm).

But when you setup a new domain you can specify a portbase and all other ports are calculated from this see [asadmin create-domain](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/6nmnj7pt9/index.html). So you can keep the default domain from GF and setup some new with the `asadmin create-domain --portbase XXXX` command and change XXXX for each other domain.